# Shard splitting names in Solr

Tags: hadoop, solr

I have 3 solr instances in my hdp cluster (3.1.5), in which I have a collection with shard1.
I splitted this shard into 2 shards, shard1_0 and shard1_1 using this command indicated in this [tutorial](https://lucidworks.com/post/shard-splitting-in-solrcloud/) :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=SPLITSHARD
&shard=shard1&name=collection1
```

The thing is that I want my splitted shards to get other names say like: shard2 and shard3 instead of shard1_0 and shard1_0

For exemple, i want to split the main shard1 into 12shards because I have 3 solr nodes. So, there's no other way to automatically split shards into the desired numbers of sub-shards. What I am willing to do is, split shard1 into 2 sub-shards, then split the sub-shards etc...

Is it possible to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The first question would be ... why? You shouldn't really have to refer to the names of the shards directly in any way. If you really want to do this, it's going to have to be a manual process as far as I know, and possibly with plenty of things that can go wrong.

Comment: For exemple, i want to split the main shard1 into 12shards because I have 3 solr nodes. So, there's no other way to automatically split shards into the desired numbers of sub-shards. What I am willing to do is, split shard1 into 2 sub-shards, then split the sub-shards etc...

Comment: But why does the names matter? Solr should handle that automagically for you behind the scenes if you're already using collections (i.e. cloud functionality).

Comment: Solr can't split shard with specific number of sub-shards given, so if I want to do that, it would be easier to name sub-shards likes 1,2,3.. rather than shard1_0_1 shard1_1_1_0_1 etc... Meaning, solr can only split shard into two sub-shard and with "_1" and "_0" in the names

Comment: Yes, I understand that - the point is - _why_ does the names matter? You shouldn't have to rely on the names in any way, as those should be handled transparently for you by Solr. What is the reason that you need to refer to a specific shard name?

Comment: it s just for easy reading and remembering, for exemple if I want to spli my shard into 8 shards : the first step is to spli shard1 into shard1_0+shard1_1 , so the second step would be to split shard1_0 into shard1_0_1+shard1_0_0, then the shard 1_1 into shard1_1_0 +shard1_1_1 and so on ... it will be easier to remember and organize the command with simple shard names

Comment: I'd probably just drop it in that case - it's an operation you'll do once, and the manual handling and possible errors introduced by doing it manually won't be worth it. In fact, the built-in scheme will allow you to know which shards you have split and which you haven't, which shardN won't. I wouldn't spend too much time on this, as it'll be something you do more or less once and then forget about it.

Comment: Yes it s a one time thing so I ll get it done this way then, thanks anyway for answering. Regards